# Require .vue single file component in PHP app

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to **require a .vue single file component to my php app** but i can't make it work without the inline template method.
So since i don't have a node main.js to import Vue and require the components, how can i require my .vue or compiled .js component to the component registration?

Working component registration:

```html
Vue.component('example-component', ({
    template: "<div>The component template</div>"
}));
```

Not working

```html
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/js/ExampleComponent.vue'));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/js/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate, but i'm getting the same error message:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

Comment: You try to run in browser? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: Oh you are right what a fail.
But i already tried to pass .vue single file components to webpack vue-loader and when i include the compiled .js file i get the error: 
**Unknown custom element: <search-request-form> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.**